# Two storyboards connected and run with two devices at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have two storyboards in my application as well as two iPhone devices. I want to connect and run both devices at the same time, meaning that the first device runs the first storyboard, and the second device runs the second storyboard.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: At a time you can run only one device!

Comment: @vivekDas you can run the same app on two devices, at the same time

Comment: you can check and load storyboards according to device types.

Comment: By connecting to your machine you can run only one at a time

Comment: @vivekDas I can run multiple. Just select another device and run. Both are running at the same time and have 2 debug consoles I can switch between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Choose your first storyboard as initial and run on one device, and at the same time choose second storyboard and run on 2nd device without stop running on the 1st device.

You will see that both devices run different storyboards.